# How to execute the Task Scheduler for eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, batch-file, selenium, testng

Currently working on **Selenium WebDriver** and using **Java**.
I have asked a question earlier to create the Task scheduler and i created as mentioned in the **[How to create scheduler to run my script every night at 12.00- Selenium WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21744795/how-to-create-scheduler-to-run-my-script-every-night-at-12-00-selenium-webdrive)**
But the Problem it is opening the eclipse at the time i have scheduled but the problem Once it open the eclipse it need to run all test one by one

I tried in cmd prompt, and getting error Error: Could not find or load main class org.testng.TestNG

Anyone please suggest me to fix the issue.

I have a run.bat as follows:

```
set ProjectPath=C:\Documents and Settings\amth\workspace\OneReports\src\
echo %ProjectPath%
set classpath=%ProjectPath%bin;%ProjectPath%lib*
echo %classpath%
java org.testng.TestNG %ProjectPath%Test.xml
```

While checking in the Command Prompt it is appearing as follows:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\amth>cd desktop

C:\Documents and Settings\amth\Desktop>run.bat
C:\Documents and Settings\amth\workspace\OneReports\src\
C:\Documents and Settings\amth\workspace\OneReports\src\bin;C:\Documents and Settings\amth\workspace\OneReports\src\lib*C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin;

 Press any key to continue . . .

java org.testng.eclipse C:\Documents and Settings\amth\workspace\OneReports\src\Test.xml

C:\Documents and Settings\amth\Desktop>
```

Is Jenkins and some other scheduler will work for windowsxp

Currently using TestNG framework, Selenium webdriver, Java code

Comment: Is there any compelling reason for you to use the windows scheduler? Are you ok to use a CI build tool like hudon/jenkins? Jenkins has an option to run a bat file

Comment: Please help me immediately to fix the windows task schedular

Comment: Follow the given link to schedule a task in windows machine. http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows/schedule-task#1TC=windows-7

Comment: Please check the above command lines when i check run.bat there is nothing happening. how can i execute the Test.xml file inside the eclipse

Comment: i have created the Task scheduler and eclipse as a schedule in Scheduled Task page. i tried with giving some time also at that particular time it start and it is opening the eclipse as well.. But the problem is once it opened it need to run the Test.xml as well. Please help me to fix the problem

Comment: please help me to figure out the problem i struck ed  nearly 3 days

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Launching eclipse for running tests one by one is a bad idea.

You just create a testsuite & launch that testsuite using batch file.

Without using testng.xml

```
import org.testng.TestListenerAdapter;
import org.testng.TestNG;

public class TestngTestSuite {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestListenerAdapter tla = new TestListenerAdapter();
        TestNG testng = new TestNG();
        testng.setTestClasses(new Class[] { ExampleTest.class,ExampleTest2.class });
        testng.addListener(tla);
        testng.run();
    }
}
```

Using testng.xml

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.testng.TestNG;
import org.testng.xml.XmlSuite;

    public class TestngTestSuiteUsingXML {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            List<String> files=new ArrayList<String>();
            files.add("/Users/test/testng/testng.xml");
            XmlSuite suite = new XmlSuite();
            suite.setSuiteFiles(files);
            List<XmlSuite> suites = new ArrayList<XmlSuite>();
            suites.add(suite);
            TestNG tng = new TestNG();
            tng.setXmlSuites(suites);
            tng.run();
        }

    }
```

Create testsuite using any of the above method and try to run testsuite from batch file by putting all required jars in classpath.

After that schedule a task in windows to run batch file

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows/schedule-task#1TC=windows-7

**Edit-1**

- Create Jar file with all your required source files. Including testsuite.
- [How to create Jar?](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/create-jar-file-in-java-eclipse/)
- [Download testng jar](http://testng.org/testng-6.8.6beta.zip)
- place both the jars in classpath while executing testsuite file.

Example:

```
Your jars & xml is in
C:\JARs> yoursource.jar, testng.jsr, testng.xml

Your testsuite must contain proper path to testng.xml
List<String> files=new ArrayList<String>();
files.add("C:\\JARs\\testng.xml");

Now try to execute testsuite 
c:\JARs> java -cp "yoursource.jar":"testng.jar" test.TestngTestSuiteUsingXML
```

Comment: @santosharma Please Can i use the above model for Testng.. where i need to place exactly the testng.xml

Comment: Could you please help  me to create exactly.

Comment: 1). You can place testng.xml anywhere. Just give that path in java file. 2). Create one jsr file using all your source files and put it in classpath. 3). Don't forgot to put testng.jar in classpath.

Put all required jars and execute it.

Comment: i'm not getting what you are telling exactly. Please check the image ![enter image description here][1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/I2vPt.jpg and explain me

Comment: @santosharma could you please explain me in detail how to do the above steps

Comment: Edited my answer. Just go through it.

Comment: I'm getting error as follows: 
C:\Jars>java -cp "OneReoprts.jar":"testng-6.8.6beta" test.TestngTestSuiteUsingXM
L
Error: Could not find or load main class test.TestngTestSuiteUsingXML

C:\Jars>

Comment: Could you please check the above image there one Test.xml is there and i have xml code inside that. I'm not getting what exactly are you telling.. whatever you have mentioned i added but its not working

Comment: I will explain you in detail. I have a project called OneReports in the path C:\Documents and Settings\amth\workspace\OneReports.

Comment: The entire project contains these many files which is shown in the image as follows  ![enter image description here][1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/I2vPt.jpg

Comment: There i have a Test.xml in that having code as follows that even in the project itself <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
 
<suite name="TestAll">
 
 <test name="test1">
  <classes>
   <class name="test.LoginOneReports" />
  </classes>
 </test>
 <test name="test2">
  <classes>
   <class name="test.OEPR_DefaultTab" />
  </classes>
 </test>
 <test name="test3">
  <classes>
   <class name="test.OEPR_InternalvsExternalTab" />
  </classes>
 </test>
</suite>

Comment: Now let me know what i need to do??

Comment: i want to know what you will give in the testng.xml

Comment: You there.. if possible come in chat

Comment: C:\Jars>dir
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 00A3-0759

 Directory of C:\Jars

02/26/2014  03:15 PM    <DIR>          .
02/26/2014  03:15 PM    <DIR>          ..
02/26/2014  02:20 PM           101,242 OneReports.jar
02/26/2014  03:04 PM               384 testing.java
05/25/2013  10:07 AM         1,429,503 testng-6.8.6beta.jar
               3 File(s)      1,531,129 bytes
               2 Dir(s)  73,268,150,272 bytes free

C:\Jars>java -jar OneReports.jar
no main manifest attribute, in OneReports.jar

C:\Jars>

Comment: give me your gmail id.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48453/discussion-between-amir-and-santoshsarma)